# using pattern while loading csv file from s3 to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

below copy command is not working , please correct me if something wrong.
`copy into mytable from  @mystage pattern='20.*csv.gz'`

here i am trying to load the files which are starts with `20`, there are mix of files which are having the name as `2021myfile.csv.gz, myfile202109.csv.gz`,   above command is not loading any files though there are files which starts with `20`.
if i use pattern as ``` pattern='.*20.*csv.gz'`` it is taking all the files which is wrong, i need to load only the files that are starts with ``` 20`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the pattern clause is a Regex expression.
Try this:

```
copy into mytable from @mystage pattern = '[20]*.*csv.gz'
```

Reference: [Loading Using Pattern Matching](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, cannot match upper cases, do you have a solution for that?